# Noteblock sound with playsound command not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am using Minecraft 1.10 and am trying to play the sound of a note block to whoever is closest. My command is:

```
/playsound note.harp block @p ~ ~ ~ 2 1
```

I have tried using 1.0 and 2.0 instead of 1 and 2. have tried replacing `@p` with my username, and have changed the volume to much higher values (10, 150, 100, 200). Nothing seems to work when all information seems to point to that being a functional command. My volumes are all on max. If you could tell me what is going on, please answer. Thank you!

Comment: Wow. 5 views, 1 answer. That went real fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`note.harp` isn't a valid sound name in 1.10. For a harp sound, you should use `block.note.harp`:

```
/playsound block.note.harp block @p ~ ~ ~ 2 1
```

On [this wiki page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sounds.json) you should use the names of sounds listed under "Sound events", but be careful of the table inconveniently below it labeled "Values as of 1.8.9", which contains the outdated values.